# ICACLS Substitute Failing "No mapping between account names and security IDs was done."

Tags: windows-server-2008, file-permissions, icacls

Running a really simple ICACLS command after I copied a directory over to a new server with permissions intact.  I need to change a SID from an old server user group to a new server user group.

Copied folder with ROBOCOPY source dest /SEC...

Got the SID of the old server user group and new server user group using PSGetSid.

```
icacls folder /save acl /t
icacls folder /substitute S-blahold S-blahnew /restore acl
```

I get an error that says:
s-blahold: No mapping between account names and security IDs was done.

I've tried replacing the SID with the servername\group.  I'm running as Administrator account that has admin access to old and new servers.

Source server is Windows 2003, destination is Server 2008.

Comment: Are the servers in the same domain?

Comment: @JoeN Yes, they are in the same domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they are in the same domain you might be able to use the friendly format, e.g. DOMAIN\USERNAME. I have found this does work when in the same domain.

The other thing is: you are prefixing the SID's with an asterisk, right?

Lastly, you could try [subinacl](http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=23510) - this allows doing an SID replace without actually looking up the object for existence in AD.

Comment: Joe, I don't believe I was prefixing the SIDs with an asterisk.  I did end up using subinacl to change the permissions.  I have another server migration coming up and I will try icacls with asterisks.

Comment: @Brad - good to hear. subinacl is a more robust tool in general.

Answer (score -1):

You could use [`subinacl`](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23510) to perform this task